# MSMQ Private queue automatically remove unread message beyond 24 hours

Tags: wcf, message-queue, msmq

I use MSMQ through WCF to store messages in private queue.
(private queue hosted by Windows Server 2003).
Messages are stored only for 24 hours and automatically removed from queue, somebody know why?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the messages have an expiry set? See [Message.TimeToBeReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.MESSAGING.MESSAGE.TIMETOBERECEIVED);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV3.5%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) property.

Answer (score 1):

Because the default value of `timeToLive` is for one day, for custom expiration, set the `timeToLive` property of `netMsmqBinding`.